# How to construct an XPath which remove text from <br> tag?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to fetch text before the `<br>` tag using XPath & Java. I tried multiple solutions, but had no luck yet.

```
//div[@class="help-block"]/p[count(preceding-sibling::br) < 1]
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="help-block">
    <p>
       This is sample text
       <br>
       Text after a breakpoint
    </p>
</div>
```

Expected outcome: `This is sample text`.
Actual outcome: `This is sample text Text after a breakpoint`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `This is sample text` Induce `WebDiverWait` And `visibilityOfElementLocated()` And get the element.

Induce `JavascriptExecutor` And get the `textContent` of `firstChild`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='help-block']/p")));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
System.out.println(js.executeScript("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;",element));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just run this:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[br]").text`

This will get the `<p>` element, but the query also checks to make sure that `<p>` contains a `<br>` element inside it. So you are just getting the `<p>`, and `.text` should get the text from the `<p>`.

Comment: Getting invalid patter issue with (//p[br]).text

Comment: @Rock Did you include the quotation marks around the XPath? ("//p[br]").text

Comment: I am checking through chropath first before running my code

Answer (score 0):

Your expression was close. But you didn't take into account that `p` is only one element and you want subnodes of `p`. So change your expression to the following (also escaping the `<` char)

```
//div[@class="help-block"]/p/node()[count(preceding-sibling::br) &lt; 1]
```

**It's output is:**

```
This is sample text
```

Comment: Why I am getting invalid patter error in the chropath when I am trying to check the presence of the element?

Comment: Maybe chropath doesn't like the escaped `&lt;`. Replacing it with `<` may help.

Comment: True, I have tried after replacing `&lt;` with `<` but now not able to identify the element. Getting an empty response.